# How to crop a image with php using jquery imgAreaSelect?

Tags: php, image, jquery-plugins, crop

i'm using the following javascript code to instanciete jquery [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) to crop my image.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ladybug').imgAreaSelect({
        onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
            $('input[name="x1"]').val(selection.x1);
            $('input[name="y1"]').val(selection.y1);
            $('input[name="x2"]').val(selection.x2);
            $('input[name="y2"]').val(selection.y2);            
        }
    });
});
```

This relates to the following (example) html code:

```
<div>
    <img id="ladybug" src="ladybug.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div>
   <form action="#" method="post">
      <input id="x1" type="hidden" name="x1" value="" />
      <input id="y1" type="hidden" name="y1" value="" />
      <input id="x2" type="hidden" name="x2" value="" />
      <input id="y2" type="hidden" name="y2" value="" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
</div>
```

[image: example imgAreaSelect]

This works perfectly, i'm getting all the right information back to php when submitting the form. However, now i have to use php to modify the image by the coordinates that the form just send. And this was harder then i thought.

```
$image_info = getimagesize($filename);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$resized_width = ((int)$formData["x2"]) - ((int)$formData["x1"]);
$resized_height = ((int)$formData["y2"]) - ((int)$formData["y1"]);

$resized_image = imagecreatetruecolor($resized_width, $resized_height);
imagecopyresampled($resized_image, $image, 0, 0, (int)$formData["x1"], (int)$formData["y1"], $resized_width , $resized_height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($resized_image, $filename);
```

The above script works but it uses the coordinates/width/height in the wrong way. i'm always left over with a big black border in the resized image:

[image: example wrong cropped image]

Can anyone set me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing the line that starts with `imagecopyresampled` with the following should do it:

`imagecopyresampled($resized_image, $image, 0, 0, (int)$formData["x1"], (int)$formData["y1"], $width, $height, $width, $height);`

`imagecopyresampled()` will take a rectangular area from src_image of width src_w and height src_h at position (src_x,src_y) and place it in a rectangular area of dst_image of width dst_w and height dst_h at position (dst_x,dst_y).